# Cython definitions across projects?

Tags: python, c++, cython

I have a Cython wrapped C++ project, `Foo` with a python wrapper that exposes some class: py_foo.Bar().  The project is defined normally using .pxd and .pyx files and installed using standard `setup.py. methods.

I have another Cython wrapped project `Baz` that has a C++ class with a constructor that takes an instance of `Foo.Bar`.  Right now, I am seeing conversion and type errors, e.g. `Bar` is not a type identifier.

Is it possible to `import`/`cimport` across projects?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely. From the [Cython documentation](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html):

> When you cimport a module called modulename, the Cython compiler
>   searches for a file called modulename.pxd. It searches for this file
>   along the path for include files (as specified by -I command line
>   options or the include_path option to cythonize()), as well as
>   sys.path.
>
> Using package_data to install .pxd files in your setup.py script
>   allows other packages to cimport items from your module as a
>   dependency.
>
> Also, whenever you compile a file modulename.pyx, the corresponding
>   definition file modulename.pxd is first searched for along the include
>   path (but not sys.path), and if found, it is processed before
>   processing the .pyx file.

The important part is the middle paragraph. In your `setup.py` file for the project where your Cython classes are defined, you need to list the `.pxd` files in the `package_data` key. For example,

```
# setup.py
setup(
    name='my_cython_package',
    packages=['example'],
    package_data={'example': '*.pxd'},  # or wherever the files are
    # ...etc...
)
```

This will cause them to be installed along with the rest of the package, and then you can cimport from them in the other project.

Comment: values of 'package_data' dict" must be a list of strings (got '*.pxd'):  
`package_data={'example': ['*.pxd']},`  
Don't forget the bracket